# Не правильно выводит сообщение на экран

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

Не могу понять почему сообщения выводятся не в том порядке,в котором созданы,то есть obj1, obj2,obj3 в main созданы друг за другом и инициализированы "1", "2", "3" соответственно,но при запуске выводится не "1,2,3", а "1,3,2", а если создать объекты в порядке obj1, obj3, obj2, то все выводится как надо,то есть "1,2,3". Сколько не смотрю на код,но не вижу проблемы(или не знаю,что именно искать т.к. только начал изучать многопоточность).

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Callme target = new Callme();

        Caller obj1 = new Caller(target, "1");
        Caller obj2 = new Caller(target, "2");
        Caller obj3 = new Caller(target, "3");

        try {
            obj1.t.join();
            obj2.t.join();
            obj3.t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Прервано");
        }
    }
}

class Callme {
    synchronized void call(String msg) {
        System.out.print("[" + msg);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Прерван");
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}

class Caller implements Runnable {

    String msg;
    Callme target;
    Thread t;

    public Caller(Callme targ, String s) {
        target = targ;
        msg = s;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        target.call(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Синхронизация гарантирует, что код в синхронизированном методе (или блоке) не будет выполняться одновременно несколькими потоками. Но вы запускаете три потока, и никто не дает гарантий, какой из них первый начнет выполнять код метода `call`.

Конкретно в вашем примере если вы уберете слово `synchronized` в методе `call`, то квадратные скобочки могут не закрыться после каждой циферки, ибо

```
void call(String msg) {
    System.out.print("[" + msg);         // один поток начинает выполнять call, выводит скобочку и циферку
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);               // этот поток засыпает
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Прерван");
    }
    System.out.println("]");             // когда он просыпается, другой поток уже успел вывести свою скобочку и циферку
}
```

Прошу заметить, что синхронизация всегда использует объект для блокировки. В случае с блоками синхронизации объект задаётся явно, случае с методами (вашем случае) этим объектом является экземпляр, на котором метод вызван.

Поэтому ваш пример будет работать до тех пор, пока все три потока обращаются к методу `call` одного и того же объекта `Callme`. Если вы на каждый `Caller` будете создавать отдельный `Callme`, то синхронизация работать не будет.

Comment: Всё понятно,но что если понадобится выводить сообщение именно так как нужно?это как-то связано с приоритетами потоков?

Comment: @NathanLight Вы можете просто сделать это в одном потоке)

Comment: @NathanLight, >>если понадобится выводить сообщение именно так как нужно?<< на помощь придут различные способы синхронизации - сигналы, семафоры или даже IpC. Выбирайте наиболее понятный вам способ, который не будет казаться избыточным и затратным, и добавляйте в код.